# iOS 10 Beta Video Playback Broken

Tags: ios, avplayer, beta, skvideonode

Using AVPlayer and SKVideoNode, code / app that was working fine with iOS 9.x is now not playing video on 10 Beta x.  The file seems to be playing, but getting the error message

```
Failed to create IOSurface image (texture)
```

This is for all for formats that have been working before (mp4, HLS, etc).

This error message seems to be coming from under the hood.

Comment: Had to use a texture to fix this and eliminate SKVIDEONODE.  Seems to work better / faster anyway.

Comment: I wonder if this is the same issue I'm having with iOS 10.0.1.  AVPlayer / AVURLAsset to play audio or video over https works fine in iOS 9.x, but stopped as of iOS 10 beta, with error "The certificate for this server is invalid."

Comment: THanks for the comment, but not getting any certificate issues in this case.  We have moved on from SKVIDEO node to CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage

Comment: @ort11 can you provide a link or example on how you solved it? pleeeeeeaseeeee

Comment: There are examples that we used for TextureFromImage on the net about BindTexture and Clamp_TO_EDGE that worked.  We eliminated SKVIDEO Node

Comment: @T'Pol I am facing similar issue. I am not able to play videos over 'https'. It was working previouslu by calling AVAssetResourceLoaderDelegate delegate methods for authentication. 
How dis you fix the issue?

Comment: @UtsavDusad I ended up changing the URL scheme to a custom one in the AVPlayerItem's asset URL, thereby forcing the AVAssetResourceLoaderDelegate delegate method to get called.  In that delegate, I change the scheme back to "https" before proceeding with the NSURLSession/DataTask calls.